# Automating Test of SDKs generated from an API against a production URL

Tags: java, go, sdk, automated-tests

We have multiple SDKs for different languages like Java, Go, Python, Node etc and maybe it will expand in future. This SDK has been generated using an open-source tool from API swagger.
I would like to know if we have any automated framework which can be used for all SDKs. I don't want to write an individual test framework for each language.